# navigating in json using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I'm using the riot games API to make something simmilar to lolking.com and this is kind of a 2 part problem, so I fetch the json data form them, but the thing is that to get the stats of a summoner from here https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/eune/v1.2/stats/by-summoner/id/summary?api_key=API_KEY_HERE you need to get his id from here https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/eune/v1.1/summoner/by-name/name?api_key=API_KEY_HERE, so I guess it's a 2 part loop using $.getJSON, so here's the code with comments

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
var input = "netuetamundis";


$(document).ready(function(){
    // get json from this page to get the ID of the input
    $.getJSON("https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/eune/v1.1/summoner/by-name/"+input+"?api_key=b05c2251-f659-4d24-8b5f-6b25a482b42a"  , function(name){
        // array to put the json data in
        var sName = [];

            $.each(name, function(key, value){
                //put the json data in the array
                sName.push(value);
                var sID = sName[0];
                //get the json from other page, now using the id of the summoner
                $.getJSON("https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/eune/v1.2/stats/by-summoner/" + sID + "/summary?api_key=b05c2251-f659-4d24-8b5f-6b25a482b42a"  , function(stats){

                $.each(stats, function(key, value){
                    //print out the data

                    $("div").append("<b>" + JSON.stringify(key) + ": " + JSON.stringify(value) + "</b></br>");

                });
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

so one of the problems is that `$("div").append("<b>" + JSON.stringify(key) + ": " + JSON.stringify(value) + "</b></br>");` repeats itself 6 times and I think this has something to do with the loop, and the second problem is that I have no idea how to naviagte through the second json I tried to do something like value[1], but it returned the whole block of data like this

```
"summonerId": undefined
"playerStatSummaries": {"playerStatSummaryType":"CoopVsAI","wins":6,"losses":0,"modifyDate":1323084313000,"aggregatedStats":{"totalChampionKills":13,"totalMinionKills":363,"totalTurretsKilled":5,"totalNeutralMinionsKilled":67,"totalAssists":40}}
"summonerId": undefined
"playerStatSummaries": {"playerStatSummaryType":"CoopVsAI","wins":6,"losses":0,"modifyDate":1323084313000,"aggregatedStats":{"totalChampionKills":13,"totalMinionKills":363,"totalTurretsKilled":5,"totalNeutralMinionsKilled":67,"totalAssists":40}}
"summonerId": undefined
"playerStatSummaries": {"playerStatSummaryType":"CoopVsAI","wins":6,"losses":0,"modifyDate":1323084313000,"aggregatedStats":{"totalChampionKills":13,"totalMinionKills":363,"totalTurretsKilled":5,"totalNeutralMinionsKilled":67,"totalAssists":40}}
"summonerId": undefined
"playerStatSummaries": {"playerStatSummaryType":"CoopVsAI","wins":6,"losses":0,"modifyDate":1323084313000,"aggregatedStats":{"totalChampionKills":13,"totalMinionKills":363,"totalTurretsKilled":5,"totalNeutralMinionsKilled":67,"totalAssists":40}}
"summonerId": undefined
"playerStatSummaries": {"playerStatSummaryType":"CoopVsAI","wins":6,"losses":0,"modifyDate":1323084313000,"aggregatedStats":{"totalChampionKills":13,"totalMinionKills":363,"totalTurretsKilled":5,"totalNeutralMinionsKilled":67,"totalAssists":40}}
"summonerId": undefined
"playerStatSummaries": {"playerStatSummaryType":"CoopVsAI","wins":6,"losses":0,"modifyDate":1323084313000,"aggregatedStats":{"totalChampionKills":13,"totalMinionKills":363,"totalTurretsKilled":5,"totalNeutralMinionsKilled":67,"totalAssists":40}}
```

Comment: remove API key while posting instead use `API_KEY_HERE`

Comment: I don't think it really matters but ok, also, here's the tidy version of the json document, since I can post only 2 links http://jsonblob.com/52c332ede4b0e85e65905f00

Comment: I think problem is in line `sName.push(value); var sID = sName[0];`, you are always sending first item from the list. thus repeats itself 6 times

Answer (score 0):

Try this Script

```
 <script>
 var input = "netuetamundis";


  $(document).ready(function(){
 // get json from this page to get the ID of the input
  $.getJSON("https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/eune/v1.1/summoner/by-name/netuetamundis?   api_key=b05c2251-f659-4d24-8b5f-6b25a482b42a", function (name) {
    // array to put the json data in
    var sName = [];

        $.each(name, function(key, value){
            //put the json data in the array
            sName.push(value);
            var sID = sName[0];
            //get the json from other page, now using the id of the summoner
            $.getJSON("https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/eune/v1.2/stats/by-summoner/" + sID + "/summary?api_key=b05c2251-f659-4d24-8b5f-6b25a482b42a"  , function(stats){
                debugger;
                $.each(stats.playerStatSummaries, function (key, value) {
                //print out the data
                    $.each(value, function (key1, value1) {

                        $("div").append("<b>" + JSON.stringify(key1) + ": " + JSON.stringify(value1) + "</b></br>");
                    });

            });
        });
    });
 });
});
```

And make sure you dont put you api keys like you did here